# How can I search IIS logs of several servers at the same time?

Tags: iis, exchange, scripting, exchange-2010, log-files

I need to search the logs of all the servers in the array for a particular string.  Specifically, I need to determine if a given user is using OWA, EWS, or something else with our CAS servers.

Is there a simple way for me to search all servers in the CAS Array in parallel?

Since this is mainly an IIS question, and Web Arrays are very common I doubt this is a "new" question but I can't find a similar answer elsewhere.

Comment: Please be a little more descriptive. The W3SVC logs? In a CAS Array? Fill in as much detail as possible

Comment: @JudasIscariot1651 - Updated... I don't think it matters what logs, just looking to search many TXT files in parallel.  Would think this is a common need since servers started scaling out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two answers are **log centralization** or **remote commands**.

See [Windows Server Event Log Collection and Analysis](https://serverfault.com/questions/59574/windows-server-event-log-collection-and-analysis) for the first and do some searching for Powershell for the second (example: [Powershell Remoting: Howto Run a Comand on multiple Machines with individual Parameters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/126432/powershell-remoting-howto-run-a-comand-on-multiple-machines-with-individual-par))

Comment: While there is dedicated software that will parse logs I'd probably write a PowerShell script to create multiple jobs across the farm

Answer (score 2):

When you start needing to cross correlate logs between servers you should really look at a central log server such as [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com). While it is possible to do so with other products like log parser, grep, etc most are designed for a single file as you have found.

Answer (score 1):

one answer logparser.exe
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659

also a good companion is Visual log parser
http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/

Examples
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692659.aspx

More examples
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/02/06/logparser-scripts-for-various-occasions.aspx

Some more examples
[Recommended LogParser queries for IIS monitoring?](https://serverfault.com/questions/45516/recommended-logparser-queries-for-iis-monitoring)

Answer (score 1):

You mean W3C logs, not event logs, right?

LogParser supports the use of multiple log files as input (i.e. *.log works in a FROM clause), so it's just a matter of consolidating the log files (or ensuring that they're accessible), which is usually fairly trivial to script.